# Python (instantiate) locks to multiple outputs

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, queue

I am working on Python multi-threading application.

The scenario is:

The source data(thousands of small files per hour) contains data about many subjects(range 1-100). Each row starts with "subject1|col1|col2|...|coln|". 
Right now users are interested in only 10(example) subjects. But in future they can add(or remove) more subjects as they prefer.

For this I wrote a program, which created a Queue and adds all source files in the directory to it. Configurable # of threads start and get a file from the queue and start parsing the data. I want to generate one large file per subject. so since user currently wants 10 subject parsed, I will generate 10 output files.

Since there can be 16-32 threads parsing the source data and writing to 10 output files, I don't want to create 10 locks, one for each output files (hard code the subject_lock per output file) since I want to provide flexibility for the program to dynamically start parsing new subject.

I am not able to think of any way to dynamically control the thread locks to the target output files (other than old school way of creating a empty file touch file(with subject_timestamp for debugging) which is generated based on the subject list, which is read from configuration file every few seconds).

Any recommendations or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will have potentially more than one thread writing to a single output file, so you want to make the writes thread-safe, while allowing another output file to be created and written to if a subject is added.

I would recommend having each thread simply lock the output file during the write. This would not prevent another output file from being created; you would simply ensure that that file gets locked during a write as well. Then, whether you have 16 or 32 threads or something in between, it doesn't matter how many output files you have -- simply ensure they are locked during the write, so any other thread that tries to write there will need to wait.

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple processes over multiple threads, and use only one process to write to a file. Check this out:

Let's say you know the directory that will contain all the files, and that at any given time, all the files need to be processed afresh. This solution will create a new file for each subject

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import csv
import os

def processFiles(dirpath, outputDirectory, numProcs):

    # create processes and queues
    fpaths, data, lines, dq = [mp.Queue() for _ in range(4)]
    readers = [mp.Process(target=fileProcessor, args=(fpaths, data)) for _ in range(numProcs)]
    writer = mp.Process(target=fileWriter, args=(lines, dq))
    for r in readers: r.start()
    writer.start()

    # let the filereaders read all the files
    for fpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, "*.txt")):
        fpaths.put(fpath)
    for _ in range(numProcs): fpaths.put(None)


    files = {}  # track each subject's output file
    done = 0
    while done < numProcs:
        t = data.get()  # get data from the filereaders
        if t is None:  # one of the filereaders died
            done += 1
            continue

        sub, data = t
        if sub not in files:
            f = open(os.path.join(outputDirectory, "{}.csv".format(sub))
            w = csv.writer(f, delimiter="|")
            files[sub] = (f,w)
        lines.put((files[sub][1], data))  # tell the writer to write out the line into that subject's output file
    lines.put(None)

    for _sub, (f, _w) in files.items(): f.close()  # close the open files
    for r in readers: r.terminate()  # kill all the readers
    dq.get()  # wait for the writer to finish
    writer.terminate()  # kill the writer


def fileProcessor(qIn, qOut):
    for infilepath in iter(qIn.get, None):  # get the filepath of the input file
        with open(infilepath) as infile:
            for sub, *data in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="|"):
                qOut.put((sub, data))  # send back the name of the subject, as well as the data
    qOut.put(None)  # time to die


def fileWriter(qIn, qOut):
    for f, data in iter(qIn.get, None):  # get the csv writer object, and the data to be written
        f.writerow(data)
    qOut.put(None)  # all data written. Time to die
```